# OpenGL obj loader doesn't work

Tags: opengl, 3d, obj

I made my own obj loader,i tried other's obj loader,but nothing works.
Here's my obj loader:

```
using namespace std;
vector<vertex> caricaobj(const char* namepath, vector<vertex> &fvertex, vector<int> &indicies)
{

    vector <float> vertex;
    vector <float> texcoord;
    vector <float> normal;







    float x, y, z;


    string s;
    string c;

    ifstream f(namepath);


    if (f.is_open()) {
        getline(f, s);
        getline(f, s);
        while (getline(f, s)) {
            if (s.at(1) == NULL) { }

            ss.clear();
            ss.str(s); 
            if (ss.peek() == '\n') {

            }


            ss >> c;




            if (c == "v") {

                ss >> x >> y >> z;



                vertex.push_back(x);
                vertex.push_back(y);
                vertex.push_back(z);

            }



            if (c == "f") {
                int temp=-1;

                string c4s;
                char c4[5]; int in = 0;

                for (int i = 0; i < ss.str().size()+8; i++) {
                    string t;

                    char d = ss.get();
                    if (d  != '/') {
                        if (d == ' ') {

                            sscanf(c4s.c_str(), "%d ", &in);  if (in != 0) { indicies.push_back(in); }      //printf("%d xzzzADS", in);
                            for (in = 0; in < 4; in++) { c4[in] = NULL; }in = 0;
                        }
                        else {
                        }


                        c4[in] = d;

                        in++;



                        c4s = c4;






                            );



                    }
                    else if (d == '/') {




                        sscanf(c4s.c_str(), "%d ", &in);     if (in != 0) {in--; indicies.push_back(in); }



                        for (in = 0; in < 4; in++) { c4[in] = NULL; }

                         in = 0; i++;

                    }   




                }
                sscanf(c4s.c_str(), "%d ", &in);in--; indicies.push_back(in);

            }






            if (c == "vt") {
                ss >> x >> y;
                texcoord.push_back(x);
                texcoord.push_back(y);


            }
            if (c == "vn") {
                ss >> x >> y >> z;
                normal.push_back(x);
                normal.push_back(y);
                normal.push_back(z);
            }



        }



        fvertex.resize(vertex.size()*3,vertex());
        int ii = 0; int i = 0;
        fvertex[i].position[ii] = vertex[x];

        fvertex[i].normali[ii] = normal[x];
        for (int x = 0; x < (vertex.size());x++ ) {
            if (ii == 3) { ii = 0; i++; x--; }
            else {
            fvertex[i].position[ii] = vertex[x];

            fvertex[i].normali[ii] = normal[x];  ii++; }



        }   fvertex[i].textcoord[ii] = texcoord[x];
        for (int x = 0; x < texcoord.size();x++) {
            if (ii == 2) {
                ii = 0; i++; x--;
            }
            else { fvertex[i].textcoord[ii] = texcoord[x]; ii++; }//if (ii == 3) { ii--; }


        }
        for (int i = 0; i < indicies.size(); i++) {


        }
    }
    return fvertex;
}
```

**I checked personally if the data were corresponding with data of the obj(with printf)**

here's one of the other's obj loader i tried:

```
vector<Vertici> loadobj(const char* namepath) {
    vector<Vertici> fvertex;





    float x, y, z;



    glm::fvec3 temp3;
    glm::fvec2 temp2;
    GLint tempint;

    vector<glm::fvec3> vert;
    vector<glm::fvec3> uv;
    vector<glm::fvec3> norm;

    vector<int> vertind;
    vector<int> uvind;
    vector<int> normind;
    stringstream ss;
    ifstream f(namepath);
    string s,prefix;
    while (getline(f, s)) {

        ss.clear();
        ss.str(s);
        ss >> prefix;

        if (prefix == "v") {
            ss >> temp3.x >> temp3.y >> temp3.z;
            vert.push_back(temp3);
        }else   if (prefix == "vt") {
            ss >> temp3.x >> temp3.y >> temp3.z;
            uv.push_back(temp3);
        }
        else    if (prefix == "vn") {
            ss >> temp3.x >> temp3.y >> temp3.z;
            norm.push_back(temp3);
        }
        else    if (prefix == "f") {
            int count = 0;
            while (ss >> tempint) {
                if (count == 1) {

                    vertind.push_back(tempint);
                }
                else if (count == 0) {

                    uvind.push_back(tempint);
                }
                else
                            if (count == 2) {

                                normind.push_back(tempint);
                            }if (ss.peek() == '/') {
                                count++;
                                ss.ignore(1, '/');
                            }
                            else if (ss.peek() == ' ') {
                                count++;
                                ss.ignore(1, ' ');
                            }if (count > 2) {
                                count = 0;
                            }
                }
            fvertici.resize(vertind.size(), Vertici());
            }
        int i = 0;
        for (size_t t = 0; t < fvertici.size(); t++) {
            fvertex[t].position = vert[vertind[t]-1];
            fvertex[t].textcoord = uv[uvind[t] - 1];
            fvertex[t].normal = norm[normind[t] - 1];
        }
return fvertex;
        }
```

i'm new to Opengl so if you can also give me a link to some tutorials step-by-stepi would be grateful.
thanks

**EDIT:now it draws something but...**

**THIS IS HOW IT SHOULD LOOK**
[image]

**AND THIS IS HOW REALLY LOOKS with glDrawElements**
[image]

**AND THIS IS HOW REALLY LOOKS with glDrawArrays**
[image]

**a sphere**
[image]

Comment: Please edit your question and add an image showing how the actual 3D model is supposed to look, for example a screenshot from the 3D modelling program the model was created in.

Comment: maybe it's better solving one thing for time.I'll make a new question about that later.

Comment: Hi, ombra oscura! Daniel_1985 made the request not to get you to ask a new question, but rather to make it more likely that anyone would take the time to answer this one. StackExchange isn't all too friendly to reading other users' code line by line. Focused questions with lots of details are preferred. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Anyhow, I used ThinMatrix's tutorial (in Java) when I first made my OBJLoader. Note that he releases a new version to fix an issue with the seams later (in Episode 16 in the playlist), but this is a good starting point to make sure you understand what's going on. Link here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YKFYtekgnP8&list=PLRIWtICgwaX0u7Rf9zkZhLoLuZVfUksDP&index=11&t=0s

Comment: @ombra osura The reason why I asked you to add an image to your question is because an image says more than 100 words. By compairing the current images, showing how the model is rendered in your application at the moment, with the image I requested, it might be easier to figure out if it's a problem with the vertices, if it's a problem with a matrix, multiplication order etc. It's easier and less time consuming to compare images than reading through a lot of hard-to-read code.

Comment: In this case, it looks like the issue is caused by incorrect matrix setup/matrix multiplication order. An incorrect matrix setup and/or incorrect matrix multiplication order can cause a lot of weird graphical issues/glitches. Please edit your question and add more relevant information about the rendering, i.e add the code for the matrix setup/matrix calculation, the rendering code and also the code for the shader(s) that is used during the render phase.